# Is there another form of probability that does not hold the axioms of standard probability calculus?

Tags: probability-theory

I am studying the philosophy of science, in particular Bayesianism. The Bayesianists accept the axioms in standard probability calculus, such as how all probabilities $p$,  $0≤p≤1$, and $p ∈ ℝ$. But I was wondering if there are any *other* probability calculi, just as there are alternatives to Euclidean geometry.

One place I really wouldn't be surprised to see this alternative would be in quantum physics. A lot of things that look extremely counterintuitive actually exist at the quantum level. An electron can spin both up and down at the same time. The Pauli Matrices involve complex numbers. So perhaps a probability of 1.2 or -0.1 doesn't seem too far fetched in the world of quantum phenomena, even if it is hard for us to imagine in our "usual" world.

> Do alternative probability calculi exist?

Comment: Quantum Mechanics uses the usual definitions in probability theory, else it wouldn't be possible to tie it back to the real world. However, you will hear talk in QM of probability amplitudes, which are complex numbers and whose moduli-squared give the probability (which is a real number bounded between 0 and 1).

Comment: A probability must be between 0 and 1 to correspond to our intuition that the probability "is" the average observed frequency...

Comment: @Tryss So goes the convention, but we could keep all else and have it be a number between pi and 0 by simply using a constant.

Comment: @zagadka314 : yes, but what would you gain by doing this? I can see what we lose, but I can't see what we gain

Comment: @Tryss I can't imagine a single thing we gain by that (except, of course, arguments to trick people, like "I am a 4.0 student" when you have a 6 point scale). But my point is that "must" is too strong there. The probability we use in our daily lives seems very intuitive, but I am curious if there is another form that can be used in some other context, or even in our "usual" world.